# How does $ work in Java?

Tags: java, gson

Silly question I know but in the google gson library I see this code:

```
import com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types;
```

in TypeToken.java

and references to this $Gson$Types thing. It appears as a syntax error. Is this $ just an allowed character for names of objects in Java?

Comment: `$` is simply a legal character for symbols, like `T`, but is "reserved" and (by convention) only to be used by the compiler, et al.

Answer (score 3):

It's allowed, but Eclipse IDE for instance tells you using it in Class name is discourage.

I believe that main reason for that being discourage is that binary name to inner class using convention of `$` for instance

```
class A {
    class B {
    }
}
```

Binary name would look something like `<somepackage>.A$B`. Nevertheless it doesn't matter since it's start from `$` in your particular case and therefor it's unique.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $ is a legal first letter for variables.
However it is strongly discouraged to do this.